# Creating a responsive navbar in bootstrap with 2 buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to create a navbar in bootstrap which has 2 options. I want the buttons to take 50% of the screen size each. I have set my div class to `<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">`

Shouldn't this indicate that on all such screen sizes, it will have 12 columns each?

Right now, when the screen is big (full screen in desktop), both the buttons are visible, however if I opt for a mobile view the buttons aren't visible.

My code is as follows:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default" id="subnav" >
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse2" style="text-align: center, margin: auto ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style=" width: 100%">
              <li class="active" style="width: 50%"><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#loginModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>  
         </div> 
    </div>
```

Updated bootply for this: http://www.bootply.com/T0rLYTBJy2#

Edit: [image: This is the screenshot currently for large screens]
[image: This is how it is coming for small screens]

I am trying to make the small screen & large screen look alike

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. On viewports over 768px you can see one dropdown button on the left and 3 links to the right, under 768px the left button is the same and the links collapse and the `navbar-toggle` button appears. By default a Bootstrap [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) isn't designed to work with columns, it can but your current use/structure doesn't have any real purpose.

Comment: @vanburen On the bootply mobile preview it does not show the 2 buttons. I do not want the 3 links to the right as I have only 2 buttons always. I am trying to create a navbar which has 2 buttons, and the whole navbar is covered with the buttons, 50% width for each button

Answer (score 1):

Here is a image of your Bootly, on a large vireport the links are exposed instead of the button on the right.

[image]

Here are two ways you could do this: one is using your current structure but making the mobile navigation "permanent" across all viewports.

The second way is just using two dropdown buttons that occupy the entire navbar.

See working Snippets at Full page.

Example 1: Current structure with mobile only `navbar`.

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
  border: 0 solid #4285f4;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media (max-width: 2500px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-left,
  .navbar-default .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-default .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="subnav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="#" style="margin-left:15px;" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default btn-plus dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color:#dd1111;"></i> Home <small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></small></a>

      <ul class="nav dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:#1111dd;"></i> Profile</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" style="color:#0000aa;"></i> Dashboard</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" style="color:#11dd11;"></i> Pages</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="color:#dd1111;"></i> Settings</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> More..</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse2"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Posts</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#loginModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#aboutModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">About</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Example 2: Just two Dropdown Buttons.

```css
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)
}
.navbar-custom .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-custom .dropdown .dropdown-menu-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-block dropdown-toggle btn-nv" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color:#dd1111;"></i> Home <small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></small>

          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:#1111dd;"></i> Profile</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" style="color:#0000aa;"></i> Dashboard</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" style="color:#11dd11;"></i> Pages</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="color:#dd1111;"></i> Settings</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> More..</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-block dropdown-toggle btn-nv" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color:#dd1111;"></i> Home <small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></small>

          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:#1111dd;"></i> Profile</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" style="color:#0000aa;"></i> Dashboard</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" style="color:#11dd11;"></i> Pages</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="color:#dd1111;"></i> Settings</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> More..</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Just Buttons: this should give you a base to style however you'd like.

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv:hover,
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv:focus,
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv:active,
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-nv {
  border: 0 solid #4285f4;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-custom .btn.btn-nv:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-block btn-nv" type="submit">Posts</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-block btn-nv" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am so sorry, but the link I had was on top of an already existing bootply link and hence you were seeing a different code from mine. I created a new link: http://www.bootply.com/T0rLYTBJy2#